# SonarQube updating manual metric via REST API sets date to January 17, 1970

Tags: sonarqube

We have an install of Sonar 5.1.2, and we're attempting to attach a performance metric to our sonar scan.  However, when we update the metric via the REST API, the metric "updated_at" is always set to January 17, 1970.  This, unsurprisingly, messes up the timeline view leaving us with only the message "Current timeline is reduced to a shorter period because of limited historical data for one of the metric."

That is, we issue the call to

```
http://statica:9000/api/manual_measures?resource=<project name>&metric=<metric name>&val=<value>
```

(And we supply the appropriate authorization for the call.

We get the response

```
{"id":3,"metric":"<metric name>","resource":"<project name>","val":17.0,"created_at":"2015-10-09T11:41:04-0400","updated_at":"1970-01-17T12:19:04-0500","login":"<user name>","username":"<user name"}
```

When we go to the site itself, and then go in to the project, then choose "Settings > Manual Measures", we can see our metric there, and in the DATE column, it shows "Jan 17 1970 12:19", which matches what was returned via the REST API.

Also, if you then go to the dashboard of the project where we have the Timeline widget configured to show the metric (as well as LOC and Coverage), we get the simple message at the bottom of "Current timeline is reduced to a shorter period because of limited historical data for one of the metric." and a single flat line in the graph.

Is this expected?  Is there any way to capture the date the metric was updated instead of this default date?  Is there a parameter we need to supply with the call to updating the metric value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This WebService is pretty old and does not comply with current WebService guidelines of SQ. It's been removed in 5.2 and replaced by WS [api/custom_measures/create](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/custom_measures/create) which does not have this issue AFAIK.

As of today, no 5.1.3 is planed, so this issue won't be fixed.

Comment: FWIW - I can confirm that this is fixed in 5.2 with the new API.